# Some of my cursor icons are gone

Tags: 14.04, gnome, cursor, cursor-theme

I recently did a full reinstall of ubuntu and then did a reinstall of gnome
(useing this guide http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/12/upgrade-gnome-3-10-ubuntu-13-10)

but some of my cursors are missing. for example I used to get a corsshairs cursor when useing the area capture in gnome-screenshot, now it's just the normal mouse. does anyone know how to get these back?

Answer (score 1):

Because you reinstalled gnome, you might have to reinstall anything that isn't packed with gnome. Follow these steps,

1. Download a cursor theme.
2. Open Gnome Tweak Tool and change the cursor theme.
   Open a Terminal.
3. Run this command:

> sudo update-alternatives --config x-cursor-theme

1. Select the number corresponding to your choice
2. Log out.
3. Log back in.